# Why the forward declaration?

Tags: c, struct

I have the following bit of code provided by a vendor for a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device.  From the code below, one can see that the struct `ble_lbs_t` is forward declared.  I am trying to understand why this is necessary in this case.  Is this an artifact of previous versions of C?  Could this have something to with the platform?  I am using the latest version of the GNU ARM embedded toolchain which uses the ARM embedded GCC compiler.  The documentation for the compiler states that it supports all GCC 5 features.

```
typedef struct ble_lbs_s ble_lbs_t;

typedef void (*ble_lbs_led_write_handler_t) (ble_lbs_t * p_lbs, uint8_t new_state);
typedef struct
{
    ble_lbs_led_write_handler_t led_write_handler; 
} ble_lbs_init_t;

struct ble_lbs_s
{
    uint16_t                    service_handle; 
    ble_gatts_char_handles_t    led_char_handles;    
    ble_gatts_char_handles_t    button_char_handles; 
    uint8_t                     uuid_type;           
    uint16_t                    conn_handle;         
    ble_lbs_led_write_handler_t led_write_handler;   
};
```

Comment: It's not *necessary* but the author presumably thought that this way would be clearer than the alternatives

Comment: `_s` must be for structure and `_t`  for type, just my guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `ble_lbs_s` struct, the `led_write_handler` member could have been written as this instead:

```
void (*ble_lbs_led_write_handler_t) (struct ble_lbs_s * p_lbs, uint8_t new_state);
```

But, the `ble_lbs_init_t` struct also has a function-pointer member (`led_write_handler`) that uses the same function signature.  So, the author chose to typedef the function-pointer type as `ble_lbs_led_write_handler_t` so it could be used in both structs, and that requires the `ble_lbs_s` struct to be forward declared before the typedef can use it.

Comment: Ok...I didn't catch the pointer function immediately below the forward declaration.  This is now kind of a big no duh as the function takes the struct itself as one of it's inputs and is part of the struct itself.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Because they didn't want to type `struct ble_lbs_s *` because `ble_lbs_t *` is shorter.
You can't use `ble_lbs_t *` without using a typedef first.  I can't think of any other reason.

Answer (score 2):

The function pointer type `ble_lbs_led_write_handler_t` uses the type defined `ble_lbs_t` The forward declaration is required for this reason.

```
typedef void (*ble_lbs_led_write_handler_t) (ble_lbs_t * p_lbs, uint8_t new_state);
```

The function pointer could also be written below the structure type. In that case, a forward declaration would not be required, but cannot comment further without seeing the full code.